# Let $X$ a set, $R$ a ring of set of $X$ and $C$ the class of subset $E$ of $X$ such that $E$ or $E^c$ $\in R$ then C is a algebra of set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set, $R$ a ring of subsets of $X$ and $C$ the class of subsets  $E$ of $X$ such that $E$ or $E^c$ $\in R$.  Then C is an algebra of sets and $C=a(R)$ (the algebra generated by $R$)

**My attempt:**

As $R$ is a ring we know satisfy this:

i)$\emptyset\in R$
ii) $A,B \in R \implies A\cup B \in R$
iii)$A,B \in R \implies A\cap B \in R$
iv)$A,B\in R \implies A-B\in R$

Let $C=\{E\subset X : E\in R \text{ or } E^c\in R\}$

We need prove $C$ is a algebra.

Note, $C$ is an algebra if:

i)$\emptyset\in C$
ii) $A,B \in C \implies A\cup B \in C$
iii)$A,B \in C \implies A\cap B \in C$
iv)$A\in C \implies A^c\in C$

By definition of $C$ the properties $i),ii),iii)$ are trivial.

Let see if $A\in C \implies A^c\in C$

> Let $A\in C\implies (A^c)^c=A\in C$ but here i'm a little stuck.

Moreover, as $C$ is an algebra then by definicion $C \subset a(R) $

I need see $a(R) \subset C$. Here i'm stuck, can someone help me?

Comment: I disagree that the properties you claim are trivial are actually trivial. Imho, the points where you ask for help are much more trivial. Can you provide the proofs for the points i,ii,iii ?